# After SSL installation "Page Not Found" Errors on every page except homepage on Apache using Symfony2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, ssl

My .htaccess file code is

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

My domain link https://www.spectrumdialogues.com/

But when I hit link it is showing homepage properly, but in every page inside menu it is showing [**Not Found**](https://www.spectrumdialogues.com/category/pharma/generics) error. Because all menu URL's generated dynamically using Symfony2 route.

What is the .htaccess configuration if URL's generated dynamically like news website article's URL's?

**Please guys help me!!!!**

Comment: Without SSL link is [http://www.biospectrumasia.com/](http://www.biospectrumasia.com/)

Comment: What is your name of start page index.php or app.php?

Comment: Start Page is **index.php** & in this file I have added code which contain in **app.php** file.

Comment: Can you show apache2 config file or Nginx config file?

Comment: I have used Apache2. But I can not access server file except my project file.

Comment: I think you `.htaccess` is OK. I think problem with your config file(Apache2)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change you Apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@yoursite.com
    ServerName yoursitename.com
    ServerAlias www.yoursitename.com
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/projects/yoursite
    <Directory "/home/admin/projects/yoursite/web/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/yousite_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/yousite_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

If this is not work, you have to see you Apache2 error file. For example `/var/log/apache2/yousite_error.log`

Answer (score 0):

In your virtual host setting

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/privatekey.pem
        <Directory /var/www/html/project>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The error is due the permission issue for your **project** directory. Adding  part resolved the issue in my case.